# vb.net alter table relationships ms access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, relationship, alter-table

My application creates a database (ms access) and creates 2 tables : tblResourceTypes and tblResources
it also creates a relationship between the two (I did this in two steps with ALTER TABLE, because I am new at this!)

```
 Using cmd As New OleDbCommand()
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE tblResourceTypes (ResourceTypeID COUNTER, ResourceType CHAR, PRIMARY KEY (ResourceTypeID))"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using

    Using cmd As New OleDbCommand()
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE tblResources (ResourceID COUNTER, ResourceType INT, Resource CHAR, PRIMARY KEY (ResourceID))"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using

    Using cmd As New OleDbCommand()
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE tblResources ADD CONSTRAINT ResourceRelationship FOREIGN KEY (ResourceType) REFERENCES tblResourceTypes(ResourceTypeID)"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
```

This gives me this relationship:
[image]

What I am looking for is a 'lookup wizard like relationship'

Where it should look like this :
[image]

All this to make it possible for the user to pull down the resourcetypes while in tblresources.

Could anybody assist in getting the syntax correct?
Thank you!

Comment: You say "in tblresources" so are you talking about doing this in Access or in VB.NET?

Comment: the creation of the database and the tables happens in VB.NET, The use will be mixed, both Access and the VB.net application - thx for such a quick reply!

Comment: Why would the first relationship prevent 'lookup'? I never use the lookup wizard because I don't build lookups in tables. Build combobox on form.

Comment: I noticed when I opened the tblResources table in access that the field ResourceType did not have a pull down/combobox like I was expecting.  I thought it was down to an incomplete/incorrecte syntax in the CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE instructions.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I already stated my preference is to not do this. I don't build lookups in tables, period http://access.mvps.org/Access/lookupfields.htm. If you must, possibly requires DAO TableDefs to modify table object. Users should not work directly with tables and queries, just forms and reports. Why do you need procedure that routinely creates db?

Comment: thank you all for your replies, if it doesn't matter I will not lose any sleep over it!  I was really just wondering if it could be done.  thanks again!